# Valet showing "Welcome to Nginx" for all sites

Tags: environment, valet

All of a sudden Valet is showing **"Welcome to Nginx"** for all my sites.

I tried restarting valet using

```
valet restart
```

I tried unsecuring a specific domain to see if it isn't a https issue

```
valet unsecure && valet secure
```

I checked if the domain is still .test by running

```
valet domain
```

But it's still showing the same default page.
What could've happened?

Comment: What is url you are trying to access to?

Comment: website.test, otherwebsite.test, ...

Comment: Turn off your nginx, `valet` and `nginx` run on the same port, so it may cause a collision

Comment: I'm with @NikolaGavric show output for `lsof -i :80`, also ´lsof -i :443´ (in case you are using HTTPS)

Comment: there seems to be nothing on :80 and a lot on :443 but doesn't seem valet related? See screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/RMqGy , thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Solution for me was running

```
sudo apachectl stop
valet restart
```

fixed it, strange because I can't imagine how having apache running can show an nginx welcome page.

Comment: Same problem here - i am looking to how uninstall apache completely. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Forced stopping nginx (`valet stop`) and running `valet install` again worked for me